# Update a array field value using field index in Angularjs array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
$scope.MyArray = [
  {id:'01', name:'test1', dept:'abc1', address: 'xyz1'},
  {id:'02', name:'test2', dept:'abc2', address: 'xyz2'},
  {id:'03', name:'test3', dept:'abc3', address: 'xyz3'}
];
```

This is my array list, I have to update the field using the column index,

for example I have a index value [2] which is field `dept`.

To update the field value as `def` at the field of  `dept` of the row `01`.

Expected result is,

```
$scope.MyArray = [
  {id:'01', name:'test1', dept:'def', address: 'xyz1'},
  {id:'02', name:'test2', dept:'abc2', address: 'xyz2'},
  {id:'03', name:'test3', dept:'abc3', address: 'xyz3'}
];
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing `dept` you need to access the `object` where you want to make change.

You can use `map` which will create a new array and inside array callback check for the `id` of the object and if that matches then update the `dept` of that object

```js
var MyArray = [{
    id: '01',
    name: 'test1',
    dept: 'abc1',
    address: 'xyz1'
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    name: 'test2',
    dept: 'abc2',
    address: 'xyz2'
  },
  {
    id: '03',
    name: 'test3',
    dept: 'abc3',
    address: 'xyz3'
  }
];

const newArray = MyArray.map((item, index) => {
  if (item.id === '01') {
    return Object.assign({}, item, {
      dept: 'newDept'
    })
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Actually my problem is Field name `dept` is dynamic, so I have to update the field value using the field index. Here `2` is the index of the field `dept`.

Thanks for your ans @brk.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by index of key

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `object` using javascript `map` function and then you can use `Object.keys` on that object to get keys and index.

Later you can check for that index using `if`.

> Here is the working example:

```
    var MyArray = [
      {id:'01', name:'test1', dept:'abc1', address: 'xyz1'},
      {id:'02', name:'test2', dept:'abc2', address: 'xyz2'},
      {id:'03', name:'test3', dept:'abc3', address: 'xyz3'}
    ];

    var changedArray = MyArray.map((item, index) => {
      Object.keys(item).map((key, i) => {
        if(i === 2) {
            return item[key] = 'test' //you can add dynamic value instead of 'test'.
        }
      })
      return item;
    });

   console.log(changedArray);
```

**output:**

```
changedArray = [
  { id: '01', name: 'test1', dept: 'test', address: 'xyz1' },
  { id: '02', name: 'test2', dept: 'test', address: 'xyz2' },
  { id: '03', name: 'test3', dept: 'test', address: 'xyz3' }
]
```